# defining averaged curve of several input graphs

Tags: python, charts, smoothing, curve

I'm trying to determine the average curve for a graph. All I have are several such graphs. The problem is that while all the graphs have the same character, they differ in length and, consequently, vary slightly. For example, curve one has a length of 4000 points, while curves two and three have about 7000-8000 points each. However, as I mentioned, the character of the curve is identical, and they don't differ much on the graph.
[Here you can see the curves](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QLqU5.png)

I've tried a lot of things to do this. The problem seems to be that I might not understand how to align them all to a single x-axis. For example, in the image, you see that

```
x_average[-1]
```

should be approximately 8. But then, when I interpolate my smaller graphs, they don't stretch out; they just draw a straight line to the end point, while the longer ones get trimmed. I also tried normalizing the graph to the largest x-value, but I wasn't satisfied with the result. Overall, if someone could give me advice on how to convert 4-5 curves with different numbers of points into a single curve that shows the average value, I would be very grateful.

```
sum = 0
for ii in displacement:
    sum += ii[-1]
  
new_x = np.linspace(0, sum/len(selected_files), 1000)
print(new_x)
new_ys = []
for jj in range(len(ys)):
    new_y = np.interp(new_x, displacement[jj], ys[jj])
    new_ys.append(new_y)
print(new_ys)
```

another try to bring them to one x-axis

```
new_disp =[]
new_ys = []    
for ii, jj in zip(displacement, ys):
    a = np.linspace(0, ii[-1], 100)
    new_disp.append(a)
    b = np.interp(a, ii, jj)
    new_ys.append(b)
    plt.plot(a,b)
    print(a)
    print(b)

x = np.mean(new_disp, axis=0)
y = np.mean(new_ys, axis=0)
```

Imagine you have several input graphs, and they all have different amounts of points. They don't share the same x and y points, meaning they might have different maximum values for x and y. However, they all have a similar curve character and slope at the beginning. I'm trying to average all the x values and, at the same time, the y values. But as I already mentioned, they all have different amounts of points. I've tried to align them all on one x-axis. This might be easier to understand if I explain that this was an experiment with identical specimens.

I've uploaded another picture to clarify what I mean. The average curve that I drew is representative of what I'm trying to achieve – it's like a mean curve across all axes.

[image: Here]

Comment: Please describe what exactly you mean by "the average curve for a graph."  Do you mean the slope?

Comment: As an example, what is the 'average curve' of a graph of y = x^2?

Comment: I think I can guess what you mean.  You want to take the average y value of several graphs at each x point and use theses new points to create a new graph.  Not "the average curve for a graph"  but more like "the average graph of several input graphs".  Please edit your question so that it makes sense

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I've made some edits to my previous explanation. Yes, my initial attempt was to find the average curve, but it's important to note that I'm looking to average both the y and x points simultaneously. The challenge is to determine these average points when each of the curves differs in length and doesn't have the same number of x and y points. So, the goal is to find a way to calculate the average x and y values together, despite the varying lengths of the curves.

Comment: Your question still says "determine the average curve for a graph."   A graph does not have a "curve", and it certainly does not have an "average curve".   You need to edit this to make sense.

Answer (score 0):

The data + example below interpolates curves from different axes onto a common x axis.

[image]

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#Test data
x0 = np.linspace(0.1, 10, 1000)
x1 = x0[::10]
x2 = x1[::5]
probe0 = np.log(x0) * np.cos(x0) ** 2 + 3
probe1 = np.log(x1 * 0.7) * np.cos(x1 + 0.5) ** 2 + 3
probe2 = np.log(x2 * 0.3) * np.cos(x2 + 0.5) ** 2 + 3

plt.plot(x0, probe0, x1, probe1, x2, probe2)

#Put axes and lines into lists
x_axes = [x0, x1, x2]
probes = [probe0, probe1, probe2]

#Find the limits to use for a common axis
# i.e. what is the min and max across all axes?
axis_min = np.inf
axis_max = -np.inf

for axis in x_axes:
    if axis.min() < axis_min:
        axis_min = axis.min()
    if axis.max() > axis_max:
        axis_max = axis.max()

#Create a common axis
n_points = 1200
common_x = np.linspace(axis_min, axis_max, n_points)

#Interpolate each curve onto the common axis
interpolated_curves = np.zeros([len(probes), len(common_x)])

for index in range(len(probes)):
    interpolated_curves[index, :] = np.interp(common_x, x_axes[index], probes[index])

#Average the interpolated curves
average_curve = interpolated_curves.mean(axis=0)

plt.plot(common_x, average_curve, linewidth=5, c='k')
plt.legend(['probe0', 'probe1', 'probe2', 'average'])
```